# Using \@ifnextchar to define a macro for "ante meridiem" time

Tags: macros, conditionals

I want to create a macro for times of days, as follows:

```
\newcommand{\pmtime}{a.m.\xspace}
```

The problem is that LaTeX thinks that the last period in a.m. denotes the end of a sentence, hence the space produced by `\xspace` is too large.

```
\newcommand{\amtime}{a.m.\ }
```

The above is not helpful either, since a regular size space is now added, even when the macro does in fact occur at the end of a sentence.

I read about `\@ifnextchar` and tried the following:

```
\newcommand{\amtime}{a.m.\@ifnextchar.{}{\ }}
```

This expands to `a.m.ifnextchar.` in the text (in this case the macro is not followed by a period.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because the letters `a` and `m` are lowercase, TeX does not think `a.m.` is an abbreviation. `\@` afterwards resets the space factor and TeX does not insert a larger space (see egreg's comment).

`\@ifnextchar` has `@` ("at") in its name, thus the pair `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` should be used (unless it is used in a package or class file). Then `@` has the catcode `letter` and can be part of a command name (see Werner's comment).

`\@ifnextchar` has the side effect of removing a following spaces, therefore the example below uses `\ltx@ifnextchar@nospace` of package `ltxcmds` that keeps a following space intact. As `\@ifnextchar` also `\ltx@ifnextchar@nospace` has three arguments, the token that is looked for (here the dot). If a dot is following, then `\@gobble` removes the dot to avoid to consecutive dots. `\xspace` is only needed for the case, that the next token is not a dot (the third argument for `\ltx@ifnextchar@nospace`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{ltxcmds}[2011/04/14]
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\amtime}{%
  a.m.\@%
  \ltx@ifnextchar@nospace.\@gobble\xspace
}
\newcommand{\pmtime}{%
  p.m.\@%
  \ltx@ifnextchar@nospace.\@gobble\xspace
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  7\amtime, 8\amtime and 9\amtime.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 10):

The `\@ifnextchar` business is already taken care of by `\xspace`, if you use it. You just need to announce TeX that the period is not ending a sentence and the command `\@` is just for that:

```
\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\amtime}{\,a.m.\@\xspace}
```

will have the correct spacing. Notice `\,` to slightly detach "a.m." from the number preceding it (and this space will never be used for a line break).

However, I usually advice against `\xspace`: it's really not so difficult to remember writing `\amtime{}` in cases when a space is needed after it.

Why don't you try with

```
\newcommand{\amtime}{\,\textsc{am}}
```

that avoids periods?

Answer (score 3):

Your use of `\@` and `\@ifnextchar` unfortunately didn't throw an error, since `\@` is a valid control sequence. The following is probably what you wanted to achieve with your use of `\@ifnextchar`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xspace
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\amtime}{a.m.\@ifnextchar.{}{\ }}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
It is 8a.m. at the moment. \par
It is 8a.m.\xspace at the moment. \par
It is 8a.m.\ at the moment. \par
It is 8\amtime at the moment.
\end{document}
```

Note the use of `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`. See [What do `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` do?](http://goo.gl/HYwLd).

However, it's easier to just use

```
It is 8a.m.\@ at the moment.
```

In the event that you might be using the macro as

```
It is 8\amtime, time to rise from bed.
```

the spacing will be incorrect. You could nest conditionals for checking the punctuation following `\amtime`:

```
\newcommand{\amtime}{a.m.\@ifnextchar.{}{\@ifnextchar,{}{\ }}}
```

However, this soon becomes clumsy. egreg's answer (using `\@\xspace`) provides a more elegant and encompassing alternative.